# Mincer-Zarnowitz for model combination, how to construct?

Tags: forecasting, model-comparison, efficiency

Lets say we have two competing models to forecast something.

We can test with the Mincer-Zarnowitz regression if model 1 is unbiased and encompessing all the information of model 2:

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \hat y_{i,1} + \beta_2 \hat y_{i,2} + \varepsilon_i$

whereas $\hat y_{i,1}$ is the forecast of model 1 and $\hat y_{i,2}$  is the forecast of model 2

by testing the null $\beta_0=0, \beta_1=1, \beta_2=0$.

If we reject this null it can be assumed that model combination can be useful.

Lets say now we combine model 1 and model 2 forecast to and obtain a third forecast.

What are useful tests to test the information efficiency of this combined forecast? I have 2 alternatives

**1. Perform again the regression above with**

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_{comb} \hat y_{i,comb} + \beta_1 \hat y_{i,1} + \varepsilon_i$

and

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_{comb} \hat y_{i,comb} + \beta_2 \hat y_{i,2} + \varepsilon_i$

and test $\beta_0=0, \beta_{comb}=1, \beta_1=0$ and $\beta_0=0, \beta_{comb}=1, \beta_2=0$

**or 2. alternatively maybe even**

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_{comb} \hat y_{i,comb} + \beta_1 \hat y_{i,1}+ \beta_2 \hat y_{i,2} + \varepsilon_i$

and test $\beta_0=0, \beta_{comb}=1, \beta_1=0, \beta_2=0$

Comment: There is something not right in your question. Perhaps you have $\hat y_{1,i}$ and $\hat y_{2,i}$ from the two models, not just a single $\hat y_i$ as in your question right now?

Comment: you were right. I just specified the formulas more precise

Comment: Another issue is how you combine the two predictions when your original test rejects the null. Do you set $\hat y_{i,comb} = \beta_1 \hat y_{i,1} + \beta_2 \hat y_{i,2}$ where $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are coefficients obtained from your original regression?

Comment: No. The weights (betas) for the combination have been derived with other methods and doesn't match with them obtained by simple regression.

Comment: This is interesting. Your problem seems like a model selection problem, and I haven't seen this approach before. Personally I prefer your second approach. It is like you are building a nested model out of the three and testing a submodel of it. Better yet, IMO, is to not fix $\hat y_{i,k}$ for $k=1,2,comb$ to pre-fitted values, but let them be free within the models and allow everything to fit to $y$ and then test whether the corresponding betas are zero. (I assume this wouldn't be called  Mincer-Zarnowitz regression anymore.)

Comment: hmm ok I understand. The problem is I don't have only 3 models at all. I actually have 10 single models and 3 combined models, giving 11 models to compare each time. Both is a mess. Compare pair wise or perform a 11 model regression, which I am pretty sure will never be not rejected. However, at least the p-values could be compared and say which of the 3 combination models is the "best" combination although not significant

Comment: 11 models is not that much. If you care about forecasting why not use cross-validation to see which one actually predicts the best. You can even use a simple leave-one-out scheme. The result is sometimes called PRESS statistic and can be obtained quite efficiently by fitting the regression once for each model. (There are closed-form formulas for it ...)